# Stability theory: Every solution of the scalar equation: $\ddot{x}+\left [a+b(t) \right ]x=0$ is bounded in $\left [t_0, +\infty \right )$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, bounded-variation

**EDITED**

Prove that: If $a>0$ and $$\int_{t_0}^{\infty} |b(t_1)|\mathrm{d}t_1<+\infty$$ then every solution of the scalar equation: $$\ddot{x}+\left [a+b(t)  \right ]x=0$$ is bounded in $\left [t_0, +\infty  \right )$.

I have thought about my problem, but I still no solution :( . Can anyone have an idea or a solution? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Please try not to use \$\$ ... \$\$ in your title because it occupies a lot more space

Comment: Thanks  Danny Cheuk! Sorry! Because I have copied from my post! :)

Comment: Is integrability the only condition on $b$?

Comment: @ **copper.hat**: Yes, it is.

Comment: @kimrahe6 $b(t)$ has to be continuous

Comment: @ **Artem**: And you're thinking about my problem! It is great if you have the answer. I hope that.

Comment: @kimtahe6 See may answer.

Answer (score 3):

Noting that solutions of $\ddot{y} + a y = 0$ have $\dot{y}^2 + a y^2$ constant,
I suspect you might start by looking at $E(t) = \dot{x}^2 + a x^2$ for solutions of your equation.

EDIT:  With $E(t)$ defined as above, you get $$\dot{E}(t) = 2 \dot{x} (\ddot{x} + a x) = - 2 b(t) x \dot{x} \le \frac{|b(t)|}{\sqrt{a}} (\dot{x}^2 + a x^2) = 
\frac{|b(t)|}{\sqrt{a}} E(t)$$
Thus $$\dfrac{d}{dt} \log E(t) = \dfrac{\dot{E}(t)}{E(t)} \le \dfrac{|b(t)|}{\sqrt{a}}$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thanks **Robert Israel**! I seem to understand your hint, maybe! But how We can show that every solution of the equation *is bounded*?

Comment: If $E(t)$ is bounded, the solutions are bounded.

Comment: Yes, **Robert Israel**! But How did you have $\ddot{y} + a y = 0 \implies \dot{y}^2 + a y^2$ is const? Can you explain to me, please! Thanks.

Comment: $\dfrac{d}{dt} (\dot{y}^2 + a y^2) = 2 \dot{y}(\ddot{y} + a y)$.

Comment: Sorry **Robert Israel**! I fixed! What did you use $\int_{t_0}^{\infty} |b(t_1) |\mathrm{d}t_1<+\infty$ and $\dot{y}$? If $\ddot{y} + [a+b(t)] y = 0 \implies \dot{y}^2 + [a+b(t)]y^2=C<C+\epsilon=M,\epsilon>0 $, then we're done! Do I understand correctly your suggestion?

Comment: I'm sorry when I say that I don't understand your hint. :(

Comment: I suspect that $E(t)$ no sense every solution of equation.

Comment: I think that we need to show It's stable then we're done. But I really have no solution.

Comment: Yes, thanks **Robert Israel**! Since $$\dfrac{d}{dt} \log E(t) = \dfrac{\dot{E}(t)}{E(t)} \le \dfrac{|b(t)|}{\sqrt{a}}$$ then by integration on $[t_0,t]$, one gets: $$\log E(t) \le \int_{t_0}^{t} \dfrac{|b(t_1)|}{\sqrt{a}} \mathrm{d}t_1$$, therefore: $$E(t) \le \exp \left( \int_{t_0}^{t} \dfrac{|b(t_1)|}{\sqrt{a}} \mathrm{d}t_1 \right) \le \exp\left( \int_{t_0}^{\infty} \dfrac{|b(t_1)|}{\sqrt{a}} \mathrm{d}t_1 \right) $$, since $\int_{t_0}^{\infty} |b(t_1)|\mathrm{d}t_1<+\infty$, we're done! Is it correct?

Comment: Almost.  It should be $\log E(t) - \log E(t_0) \le \ldots$.

Comment: @ **Robert Israel**: Yes, I missed $\log E(t_0)$ in RHS! Ok! I have a stupid question: I think that If $E(t)$ is a solution of the equation $$\ddot{x}+\left [a+b(t)  \right ]x=0$$ then $\ddot{E(t)}+\left [a+b(t)  \right ]E(t)=0$?

Comment: I felt so ashamed of my haste, now, I rewrite:( $$\int_{t_0}^{t}\left ( \log E(t)  \right )' \mathrm{d}t  \le \int_{t_0}^{t}\dfrac{|b(t)|}{\sqrt{a}}\mathrm{d}t$$ 
 $$\iff \log\left (\dfrac{E(t)}{E(t_0)}  \right )\le \int_{t_0}^{t}\dfrac{|b(t)|}{\sqrt{a}}\mathrm{d}t$$
$$\iff \dfrac{E(t)}{E(t_0)}\le \exp\left (\int_{t_0}^{t}\dfrac{|b(t)|}{\sqrt{a}}\mathrm{d}t  \right )$$ $$\iff E(t) \le E(t_0)\cdot \exp\left (\int_{t_0}^{t}\dfrac{|b(t)|}{\sqrt{a}}\mathrm{d}t  \right )$$

Comment: Why would you think $\ddot{E}(t) + [a+b(t)] E(t) = 0$?  It's clearly false in the case $b(t) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Write as a 2-dimensional differential equation in matrix form by defining $y = \dot x$. Then Use the Gronwall Lemma (or the version known as the Bellman-Gronwall Lemma) to treat the time-dependent "small" part that depends on $b(t)$ as a perturbation of the time-invariant stable system. (A textbook in adaptive control such as Sastry & Bodson, Ioannou & Sun, or Narendra & Annaswamy well set you in the right direction on the use of the Bellman-Gronwall for stability analysis of your problem).

Then let me know whether your system is indeed stable for any $b(t)$. I suspected not, because the time-invariant unperturbed system is merely stable, not asymptotically so, and the time-varying perturbation could be chosen to resonate with its modes, which are $i\sqrt{a}$ and $-i\sqrt{a}$, but Artem's argument shows that it is indeed stable. Thanks!

Comment: @ **pait**: you mean stable $\iff$ every solution of the scalar equation is bounded. Ok. But you suspect that system is not stable? No, I don't think so.

Comment: @pait The system is stable for any $b(t)$ with convergent integral

Answer (score 2):

I will give you a general result.

Your equation can be rewritten as a system of two first order equations, in the general form
$$
\dot u=(A+B(t))u,\quad u=(u_1,u_2)^{\top}.
$$
Assume that the system 
$$
\dot u=Au
$$
has the fundamental matrix solution 
$$
\Phi(t)=\exp(At).
$$
Since the eigenvalues of $A$ have zero real parts, it can be shown that
$$
\|\Phi(t)\|\leq C
$$
for some constant $C$.

Now look for a solution of the original system in the form $u=\Phi(t)z$. After simplifications you should be able to find
$$
\dot z=\Phi^{-1}(t)B(t)\Phi(t)z.
$$
Hence the solution to the system can be written as
$$
u(t)=\Phi(t)u_0+\int_0^t\Phi(t-\tau)B(\tau)u(\tau)d\tau.
$$
From the last, we have
$$
\|u\|\leq C\|u_0\|+\int_{0}^tC\|B(\tau)\|\|u(\tau)\|d\tau.
$$
By Grownwall's inequality this is the same as
$$
\|u\|\leq C\|u_0\|\exp( C\int\|B(\tau)\|d\tau),
$$
which proves that the solutions are bounded.

Comment: I know http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality

Comment: But what you say is too difficult for me to find a solution for my problem. :(

Comment: @kimtahe6 This post gives you a solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand! You can add hints? Thanks.

Comment: "Since the eigenvalues of A have zero real parts" should perhaps be replaced by "Since the eigenvalues of A have nonpositive real parts and there are no double eigenvalues with zero real part".

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

- By leting: $u_1=\dot{x}$, $u_2=\dot{u_1}$ then we have:
  $$\begin{cases}
   & \text{  } \dot{u_1}=u_2 \\ 
   & \text{  } \dot{u_2}=-[a+b(t)]u_1 
  \end{cases}$$
  Hence,
  $$\begin{bmatrix}
  \dot{x}\\  \ddot{x}\\
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
   &0&1\\ 
   &-(a+b(t)& 0
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
  x\\  \dot{x}\\
  \end{bmatrix} \implies \frac{dv}{dt}=A(t)v, (2)$$.

Now, We need to show that all the solutions of the scalar equation:$$\ddot{x}+\left [a+b(t)  \right ]x=0, (1)$$ are bounded.

- We have $\dfrac{dv}{dt}=A(t)v$ can be rewrite:
  $$\begin{bmatrix}
   &0&1\\ 
   &-(a+b(t)& 0
  \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
   &0&1\\ 
   &-a& 0
  \end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}
   &0&0\\ 
   &-b(t)& 0
  \end{bmatrix}=A+B(t)$$.
  The solution $v(t)$ of (2) such that:
  $$v(t)=e^{At}\cdot v(t_0)+\int_{0}^{t} e^{(t-s)A}\cdot B(s) \cdot v(s)\mathrm{d}s$$.
- Now, since **Artem**'s hints, implies $v(t)$ is bounded!

I did exactly as what you say! Is it correct?

---

**Here's my solution:**

Aplying the **Theorem**:

> Assume that:
>
> - The system: $$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=Ax$$ is stable.
> - And $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\|B(s)\|\mathrm{d}s<\infty$$ Whence, system: $$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=[A+B(t)]y$$ is stable.

Now, $A=\begin{bmatrix}
 &0&1\\ 
 &-a& 0
\end{bmatrix}$; and $B=\begin{bmatrix}
 &0&0\\ 
 &-b(t)& 0
\end{bmatrix}$. QED.