# solution of a system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A$ an $n \times n$ matrix and let $B(x)$ a continuous $n \times n$ matrix, and for $x \geq 0$ and a vector $Y$ with $n$ components, we consider the system 
$$Y' = (A+B(x))Y\tag{2}$$
If all solutions of the problem 
$$Y' = AY\tag{3}$$
are bounded, what's the conditions of $B(x)$ in order that all solution of $(2)$ are bounded on positive real line?

Comment: If the solutions of (3) are bounded, what do you know about the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$? What then do you know about the solution of Lyapounov matrix equation ($HA+A^\ast H=-I$)? How would you modify the resolvent of the system (3) to obtain the resolvent of system (2)?

Comment: To obtains an solution of (2), we must add an particular solution to the solution of (3). But what's the method to prouve this exercice?

Comment: Nope, the sum of a solution of (2) and a solution of (3) won't give us the solution of (3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition is that
$$
\int_{x_0}^\infty\|B(\xi)\|d\xi
$$
exists.

If the solutions to 
$$
Y'=AY
$$
are not only bounded but approach zero (the origin is asymptotically stable) then the condition can be weakened as
$$
\|B(x)\|\to 0
$$
as $x\to\infty$.

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491306/stability-theory-every-solution-of-the-scalar-equation-ddotx-left-abt/494082#494082) you can find a proof for the former. This proof can be adapted for the latter statement.

Comment: I have question please! The fundamental system $$Y'=AY$$ has the fundamental matrix solution $$\Phi(t)=e^{At}$$ Since the eigrnvalues of $A$ has zero real parts, it can be shown that $$||\Phi(t)||\leq C$$ for some constant $C$. I don't understand this point. Now, we look for an solution of the original system in the form $$^Y_p=\Phi(t)Z$$ is it an particular soltion? ans $Z$ is an function on $t$?

Comment: @grg $\|\Phi(t)\|\leq C$ in given in your problem. This exactly means that solutions are bounded. For the second question: This a change a variables, instead of unknown function $u(t)$ function $z(t)$ is taken.

Comment: But what's the meaning of "since the eigenvalues of $A$ has zero real parts"? I don't understant the relation with eigenvalues of $A$

Comment: The eigenvalues of $A$ determine whether the solutions are bounded or not.

Comment: if the soution of the homogeneous problem is bounded, then automatically we have that the eignevalue of $A$ has zero real parts? But why? And in my exercice we don't have information of the eignevalues of $A$.

Comment: @grg If solutions are bounded than the real parts of the eigenvalues are non-positive. In your exercise you do not need this information, because you are just given the fact that solutions are bounded.

Comment: Please, please can you explain me the point $Y_p(x)=\Phi(x)Z(x)$ how we found $Z'(x)=\Phi^{-1}(x)B(x)\Phi(x)Z(x)$? and why $Y(x)=\Phi(x)Y_0+\int_0^x \Phi(x-\tau)B(\tau)Y(\tau)d\tau$? Can you help me to develop this point please, and understand how we need to take $Z(x)$?